# How to add a delete link

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I'm trying to add a delete link button below the 'action' column which deletes an entry when clicked. I've created the delete.php file but i've been unsuccessful in creating a url to link it.
The code below outputs the data in the 'receipt' table from my database....is it possible? how do i do it??

```
<?Php
require "config.php";           

$page_name="currentout.php";  
$start=$_GET['start'];
if(strlen($start) > 0 and !is_numeric($start)){
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}


$eu = ($start - 0); 
$limit = 10;                                 
$this1 = $eu + $limit; 
$back = $eu - $limit; 
$next = $eu + $limit; 

$nume = $dbo->query("select count(id) from receipt")->fetchColumn();


echo "<TABLE class='t1'>";
echo  "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Pass</th><th>Amount</th><th>Action</th></tr>";


$query=" SELECT * FROM receipt  limit $eu, $limit ";


foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row) {

@$m=$i%2;
@$i=$i+1;   
echo "<tr class='r$m'><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[phone_num]</td><td>$row[Amount]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

if($nume > $limit ){ 
echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='30%'>";

if($back >=0) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$back'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>"; 
} 

echo "</td><td align=center width='30%'>";
$i=0;
$l=1;
for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit){
if($i <> $eu){
echo " <a href='$page_name?start=$i'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>$l</font></a> ";
}
else { echo "<font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red>$l</font>";}        
$l=$l+1;
}


echo "</td><td  align='right' width='30%'>";

if($this1 < $nume) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$next'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a>";} 
echo "</td></tr></table>";

} 
?>
```

Comment: `<a href="delete.php?id=$id">delete</a>`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'delete' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: So find which causes this error. Or create a question if you can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your this line

```
echo "<tr class='r$m'><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[phone_num]</td><td>$row[Amount]</td></tr>";
```

to

```
echo "<tr class='r$m'><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[phone_num]</td><td>$row[Amount]</td><td><a href='delete.php?id=$id'>delete</a></td></tr>";
```

Create a new file `delete.php`

```
<?php
$sql = "DELETE FROM receipt  WHERE ID=  :ID";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $_GET['id'), PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$stmt->execute();
header('location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: I am pretty bad with syntax :D

Comment: @yiiframe Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\table\out\delete.php on line 5                                      After adding ']' in line 4.

Comment: <?php
require "config.php";
$sql = "DELETE FROM receipt  WHERE ID=  :ID";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $_GET['id'];, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$stmt->execute();
$conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
header('location: currentout.php');
?>